# Find opened windows

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, window

I have a web application done in Ext js. Upon log-out I have to close all opened windows. Is there any mechanism to detect all open windows? Other idea would be to store information about open windows elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done something like this.

```
var windowManager = Ext.WindowManager;
windowManager.each(function(wind) {
    console.debug("window");
    console.debug(wind);
    wind.close();
});
```

But I am not completely sure that all windows found would have the `close` method implemented, which would lead to exceptions. Can someone confirm this?

**EDIT**: Possible way to ignore exeptions

```
if (typeof wind.close != "undefined"){
        wind.close();
    }
```